# Why the domain of $fg(x)$ is not equal to intersection of the domains of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$?

Tags: calculus

If $f(x) = \sqrt{x-1}$ and $g(x) = \sqrt{x+1}$ then why the domain of $f(x)\cdot g(x)= \sqrt{x^2 - 1}$ is not equal to $D_f\cap D_g$?

Answer (score 3):

The domain of function $fg$ prescribed by $x\mapsto f(x)g(x)$ surely is $D_f\cap D_g$.

The function prescribed by $x\mapsto\sqrt{x^2-1}$ is another function that coincides with $fg$ on the domain of $fg$.